# Change table name for admin grid collections

Tags: magento, collections, alter-table

I have created one module for banner. Its working well. In backend, I have an option to add banner image and set active or not.Initially, I have created a table with the name "**banner**" for save banner records.

Now I would like to change the table name like **chilly_banner**. I have created "**chilly_banner**" table manually in DB and inserted some records.

In admin banner grid, I want to show the collections from this table. I don't have any idea, how to do it. But i have tried like this in **_prepareCollection()** method,

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('banner/chilly_banner')->getCollection();
```

And in model file **_init()** method changed banner into **chilly_banner** as like above.

But I got an error like

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object
 in ../app/code/local/Chilly/Banner/Block/Adminhtml/Banner/Grid.php on
 line 18
```

Have any idea how to change table name in **grid collections** and also want change the table name in **saveAction()** method too?

I'm eagarly awaiting for your response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is model name that you changed, if you like to change the table name then go to config.xml and search for

then replace the argument inside that table
from

```
<table>banner</table>
```

to

```
<table>chilly_banner</table>
```

then everywhere in your module, chilly table will use automatically

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have reverted my all changes, and applied your solution. But i got an error like ""Can't retrieve entity config: banner/banner"

Comment: is there any line number or file mentioned in error response. might be table name is calling, without using model